# Add previously ignored directory to Git repository

Tags: linux, git

My `.gitignore` file looks like:

```
html/
cache/
resources/
# Temp files often created by editors
*.~
```

I know wish to start tracking a specific directory in html, so I add `!html/support/

```
html/
cache/
resources/
# Temp files often created by editors
*.~
# Track support
!html/support/
```

After doing so, however, Git still doesn't seem to track html/support/ and all its children.

How do I add a previously ignored directory to Git repository?

Comment: `git` doesn't track directories. It tracks files, and only the ones you tell it to. You have to specifically tell it to start tracking something with `git add ...`.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

**Not ignoring doesn't mean tracking.**

Just use

```
git add html/support/
```

at the root of your git repository.

If the file is still ignored, though, you can use `git add -f` to force adding it (this will not modify the `.gitignore` file, just allow one little exception) :

```
git add -f html/support/
```

Comment: Thanks blue,  For my example, would that be `git add html/support`?

Comment: Yes, it would be that.

Comment: Do you have to restart git or something after changing .gitignore?  When I try to add the directory, I get `The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files: html/support. Use -f if you really want to add them. fatal: no files added`.

Comment: @user1032531 - use the `-f` option, as suggested, when adding the files. The message you're seeing just means the repository is still set up to ignore the directory. As a corollary to blue112's answer, you can still forcefully add files to be tracked in the repo even if they are considered as ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Your `.gitignore` should add this line:

```
!html/support/**
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply go to the Directory of the File where **.gitignore** file is located. This File contains all the files that are ignored. You can simply remove the file listing and save it. Then Refresh your project. Then you will be able to commit those files.